# How to AddTorque towards an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two cubes. One of them must rotate towards the other one all the time. The things is that the other cube always changes its position. Here is an image that explains what i need.

[image: Example]

I tried to AddTorque to the direction between them but it did not work.

```
transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(transform.position - OtherCube.transform.position * 10f * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

The rotating cube's face not always looking to other cube so it should rotate without looking to the other cube. (I meant it should rotate from closest face or edge or anywhere. does not matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cross product to find the axis you're interested in, taking into account the direction of the ground:

```
private Rigidbody rb; 

void Start() { rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); } // cache results of GetComponent

void TurnTowards() 
{
    Vector3 groundDirection = Vector3.down;
    Vector3 towardsOther = (OtherCube.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Vector3 rotateAxis = Vector3.Cross(towardsOther, groundDirection);

    float rotateMagnitude = 500f; // tune as necessary

    rb.AddTorque(rotateMagnitude * Time.smoothDeltaTime * rotateAxis);
}
```

Comment: Hi again Ruzihm, you saved the day again! Thank you, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier if you use an empty object as the father of the cube, freezing movement in the cube.

With that, you can make the parent just LookAt the other cube, and the cube just AddTorque on his X axis, the code will be simple like this:

```
private Transform parent;
private Rigidbody rb; 

void Start() { 
    parent = transform.parent;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
} 

void Update() 
{
    Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
    parent.LookAt(otherCube.transform);
    transform.rotation = rot;
    rb.AddTorque(rotateMagnitude * parent.right);
}
```

Comment: Asker doesn't always want the subject cube to rotate/torque along its local x axis. If you take this approach, you should keep `transform.rotation` constant before and after `parent.LookAt` and then `rb.AddTorque(parent.right * rotateMagnitude);`. I edited the answer to adopt this fix.

Comment: Yeah Ruzihm is right. I do not want my main cube's face to look at the other cube. I want it to rotate towards wherever the other cube's direction from any face or any point of it currently at. @Ruzihm 's algorithm does exactly what i needed.

Comment: Oh, ok, I unerstood the cube rotating towards the other cube, like a wheel who wants to run over it :P